# Echo skip JWT middleware

Tags: go, jwt, go-echo

I used golang jwt middleware.

```
e.Use(middleware.JWTWithConfig(middleware.JWTConfig{
  SigningKey:  []byte(os.Getenv("Signing_Key")),
  TokenLookup: "header:x-auth-token",       
}))
```

It waits token for all functions but I don't want to use this middleware for login function. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [`skipper` function](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/jwt/). You can use it to check which route to skip.

```
JWTConfig struct {
  // Skipper defines a function to skip middleware.
  Skipper Skipper
  ... 
}
```

Check an **example**:

```
e.Use(middleware.JWTWithConfig(middleware.JWTConfig{
    SigningKey:  []byte(os.Getenv("Signing_Key")),
    TokenLookup: "header:x-auth-token",
    Skipper: func(c echo.Context) bool {
       // Skip middleware if path is equal 'login'
       if c.Request().URL.Path == "/login" {
         return true
       }
       return false
    },
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this

```
e.Use(middleware.JWTWithConfig(middleware.JWTConfig{
    SigningKey:  []byte(os.Getenv("Signing_Key")),
    TokenLookup: "header:x-auth-token",
    Skipper: func(c echo.Context) bool {
       return c.Request().URL.Path == "/login"
    }
}))
```